# When to use CardView instead of BaseCardView? And vice versa

Tags: android, android-cardview

CardView and BaseCardView in Android.

Are those interchangable?
I'm trying to find out what card is better in certain practical cases.

Are there certain practical cases (for example - platform: TV, tablet or smartphones) where we have to use BaseCardView only? And vice versa. 
What one card can do that another one can't.

As we know both extend FrameLayout, but what is the principal difference between these cards?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is `BaseCardView`? Is this a Widget in new Material.IO ?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "better" (nicer, faster, easier to use, smaller code size, ...)?

Comment: not "nicer" because it is very subjective,
I'm talking about principal difference, what is faster,  which one has better flexibility. In what cases we can use BaseCardView only or vice versa.